# Java android - uplaud apk and google play security alert

Tags: java, android

When I update a apk to google store a google play send to me a security alert ,. This is a mail :

We rejected ****, with package name *****, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

```
This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
TrustManager
You can find more information about TrustManager in this Google Help Center article.

10
To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.

While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.

Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies.
```

And this is my code in which I implement a TrustManager :

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);
        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

And this is my build.gradle :

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.3.1-2@aar'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    compile 'dk.ilios:realmfieldnameshelper:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

Answer (score -1):

do u already try to implement the checkValidity() statement? take a look of this:

```
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    try {
        chain[0].checkValidity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I try this but it doesn't help me